# Use of HIghlighter in PieChart : jQplot

Tags: javascript, graph, jqplot, pie-chart

I want to use Highlighter functionality in to a PieChart. My code is

```
function device_ownership_graph(titleOfGraph, corporateOwned,
        corporateShared, employeeOwned) {

    var arrCorporateOwned = [ 'Corporate-Owned', corporateOwned ];
    var arrCorporateShared = [ 'Corporate-Shared', corporateShared ];
    var arrEmployeeOwned = [ 'Employee-Owned', employeeOwned ];

    $.jqplot.config.enablePlugins = true;
    /*Here we construct graph*/
    $.jqplot('device_ownership_graph', [ [ arrCorporateOwned, arrCorporateShared, arrEmployeeOwned ] ], {
        title : {
            text : titleOfGraph, // title for the plot,
            show : true,
            fontSize : 14,
            textColor : '#808080',
            textAlign : 'center'
        },
        seriesColors : [ "#00b0f0", "#ffc000", "#92d050"],
        seriesDefaults : {
            // Make this a pie chart.
            renderer : jQuery.jqplot.PieRenderer,
            shadow: false,
            rendererOptions : {
                // Put data labels on the pie slices.
                // By default, labels show the percentage of the slice.
                showDataLabels : true,
                startAngle: 90,
                sliceMargin: 1,
                //highlightMouseOver: true
                highlightMouseDown: true

            }
        },
        legend : {
            renderer : $.jqplot.PieLegendRenderer,
            show : true,
            rendererOptions : {
                numberRows : 1,
                numberColumns : 3,
                disableIEFading : false
            },
            location : 'n',
            placement : 'outsideGrid',
            marginTop : '0px',
            marginBottom : '0px'
        },
        grid : {
            drawGridlines: false,
            show : true,
            background : 'transparent',
            borderWidth : 1,
            shadow : false
        },
        highlighter: {
            showTooltip: true,
            tooltipFade: true
        }

    });
    $('#device_ownership_graph .jqplot-data-label').css('color', '#000000');

    $('#device_ownership_graph').bind('jqplotDataHighlight', function (ev, seriesIndex, pointIndex, data) { alert('series: '+seriesIndex+', point: '+pointIndex+', data: '+data);}); 
}
```

### Problem

I am getting two different errors in two different browsers when mouse-move event on slices.

Chrome : -

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'formatter' of undefined jqplot.highlighter.min.js:57
```

Mozila :-

```
q._xaxis._ticks[0] is undefined
```

And one more issue, when I use `highlightMouseDown: true` its working (showing an alert) but when I use `highlightMouseOver: true` its not working.

***What am I doing wrong in my code? Please help me.***

---

UPDATE : 22 Jan 2013

---

I want the behavior of highlighter as it works in BarGraph. I used `alert()` in my given code, but that code is only for testing of highliter.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Both of the errors you are getting refer to the same problem. This line in `jqplot.highlighter.min.js` is the one:

```
var w=q._xaxis._ticks[0].formatter;
```

Chrome can't access the `formatter` property because `q._xaxis._ticks` is undefined (as reported in Firefox).

The solution (inspired by [How to display tooltips on jqplot pie chart](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8209474/how-to-display-tooltips-on-jqplot-pie-chart)) is to add the following code into your `seriesDefaults` configuration:

```
highlighter: {
    show: true,
    formatString:'%s', 
    tooltipLocation:'sw', 
    useAxesFormatters:false
}
```

In your case, `seriesDefaults` would then look like:

```
seriesDefaults:{
    // Make this a pie chart.
    renderer : jQuery.jqplot.PieRenderer,
    shadow: false,
    rendererOptions : {
        // Put data labels on the pie slices.
        // By default, labels show the percentage of the slice.
        showDataLabels : true,
        startAngle: 90,
        sliceMargin: 1,
        highlightMouseOver: true
        //highlightMouseDown: true
    },
    highlighter: {
        show: true,
        //formatString:'%s', 
        //tooltipLocation:'sw', 
        useAxesFormatters:false
    }
}
```

The important thing is setting `useAxesFormatters` to false. Pie graphs don't have axes, hence the earlier error regarding `q._xaxis._ticks` being undefined.

Note that you will likely need the commented out `formatString` and `tooltipLocation` properties when you move away from using `alert`-based tooltips.

**Edit:**

I am assuming you mean the kind of highlighting that is found on this page: http://www.jqplot.com/deploy/dist/examples/barTest.html

In that last `highlighter` configuration you currently have:

```
highlighter: {
    showTooltip: true,
    tooltipFade: true
}
```

If you just want the highlighting effect and no tooltip, set `showTooltip` to `false`. Then remove the line of code where you bind to the `jqplotDataHighlight` event. This should ensure that the highlight effect will show up.

Comment: Hi nick_w Actuaaly I don't want to use alert... I added that code because that was only working code for highlighter. I want the same behavior as in BarGraph for highlighters. Please help me

Comment: @AndroidLearner can you update the question with the kind of behaviour you are wanting?

Comment: Edited my question... please review.

Comment: +1. Thank you very much.. I ll update my code and test. After I will inform you. Thanks again.

Comment: Still not working. Now it has a problem on line 488 "var af = plot.axes[g[j]]._ticks[0].formatter;" Cannot read property 'formatter' of undefined . Did you found a solution?

Comment: but now ti blocks on the cursor.js file line 488

Comment: @DavidGraça Which version of jqplot are you using?

Comment: latest version 1.0.8. Are you guys getting JS errors anytime you pass with the mouse over the pie?

Answer (score 0):

The previous answers do not work for me: it turns out that if you include `jqplot.cursor` it will break the pie chart.

To make it work again you need to have cursor:

```
{ show: false }
```

as part of your pie chart `seriesDefaults` options.

Comment: Whoops - not as part of seriesDefaults but as part of the pie chart options.