# jqPlot Pie Chart Tooltips

Tags: jquery, tooltip, pie-chart, jqplot, jqplot-highlighter

Am I right in thinking that the Hightlighter class in jqPlot does not handle tooltips for the PieRenderer? I've spent quite a while trying to get them to work however I can't seem to get it to show the tooltip.

If I am right, is there a way to handle the rollover of a segment and pass the data to a third party jQuery tooltip?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking through the [issues](https://bitbucket.org/cleonello/jqplot/issues?q=tooltip) for jqplot, it would seem that there have been a few requests for this functionality, but it has not yet been implemented.

Based on this question [How to display tooltips on jqplot pie chart](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8209474/how-to-display-tooltips-on-jqplot-pie-chart), you could wire up the `jqplotDataHighlight` and `jqplotDataUnhighlight` events:

```
$("#chartId").bind('jqplotDataHighlight', function(ev, seriesIndex, pointIndex, data) {

}); 

$("#chartId").bind('jqplotDataUnhighlight', function(ev, seriesIndex, pointIndex, data) {

});
```

There is a good example of using this technique to create custom tooltips [here](http://www.jqplot.com/tests/bubble-plots.php). Although it is dealing with bubble charts, it should point you in the right direction.

You could also try out the [jqplot-highlighter](https://github.com/tryolabs/jqplot-highlighter) plugin, which allows tooltips for pie charts.

Comment: Thanks - I used this method and created a custom tooltip.

Answer (score 4):

if you are using the  Highlighter plugin, remember to set useAxesFormatters: false or it don't work.

```
highlighter: {
    show: true,
    useAxesFormatters: false, // must be false for piechart   
    tooltipLocation: 'w',
    formatString:'%s, %P',
}
```

It don't follow the mouse but it's set in the top left corner.

Comment: Thanks, I tried implementing the Hightlighter class in using these parameters before-hand but it would just never show.

Comment: Do you get any error messages? (in firebug, dragonfly or similar debugging tools?)

Comment: Worked for me. Thanks. But the tooltip is hiding behind the pie chart