# Display Value with Pie Chart

Tags: jquery, charts, jqplot

I am using `jqplot` plugin for charts. I have created pie chart but i want to display value same as display in below image.

[image]

Any option for this? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$("#chartId").bind('jqplotDataHighlight', function(ev, seriesIndex, pointIndex, data) {

}); 

$("#chartId").bind('jqplotDataUnhighlight', function(ev, seriesIndex, pointIndex, data) {

});
```

Refrence **[Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8209474/how-to-display-tooltips-on-jqplot-pie-chart)**,
**[Link2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15474242/jqplot-pie-chart-tooltips)**

And can also **[try](https://github.com/tryolabs/jqplot-highlighter)**