# Show percentage in jqplot piechart tooltip

Tags: javascript, primefaces, jqplot, jqplot-highlighter

I'm using primefaces with jqplot library.

In my piechart i have the extender property and in the javascript function i have this:

```
this.cfg.highlighter = {
     show:true,
     tooltipLocation: 'n',
     tooltipAxes: 'y',
     useAxesFormatters: false,
     tooltipFormatString: '%s'
}
```

The tooltip shows section value, but not section percentage.

Anybody knows how to show percentage value in tooltip?

Thanks.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to display tooltips on jqplot pie chart](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8209474/how-to-display-tooltips-on-jqplot-pie-chart)

Comment: I saw that post, it's not duplicated, i want to show another data. Thansk.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can bind the highlight event in order to modify the tooltip :

```
$("#chart1").bind('jqplotDataHighlight', function(ev, seriesIndex, pointIndex, data) {
 var highlightToolTip = $(".jqplot-highlighter-tooltip");   
 var pct = Math.round(data[1]/total*100);
 highlightToolTip.html(data[0]+", "+pct+"%");  
});
```

Where :

- data[1](http://jsfiddle.net/AnthonyLeGovic/dFgGj/538/) is the value of the highlighted slice,
- data[0] is the label of the highlighted slice,
- total is a variable containing the total value of your plot built here :

  ```
   data = [
      ['Heavy Industry', 12],['Retail', 9], ['Light Industry', 14], 
      ['Out of home', 16],['Commuting', 7], ['Orientation', 9]
  ];

  var total = 0;
  $(data).map(function(){total += this[1];})
  ```

Please see a working example on 
       [fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/AnthonyLeGovic/dFgGj/538/)

Comment: Doesn't seem to work anymore. I had to change `jqplotDataHighlight` tot `jqplotDataMouseOver`. I wonder if there's a better way.