# Implement ToolTip feature in Line Chart

Tags: jsf, primefaces, jqplot

I Have implemented a Primeface 3.5 line chart.I have also  added the tool tip feature.
Now I want is that , if I click on the coordinate , it should show me the origination of those points.
**eg:**
  The highlighted coordinate 2006 is summation of (1000 + 1006), so when I place my cursor on the point it should show me (1000+1006).

How do I implement the feature?
  *as short of reputation I could not upload the image to explain it*

Answer (score 0):

In `jqplot` attributes, you can specify to show the value on `x` axis, `y` axis or `both` in `tooltipAxis` attribute.

Alternatively, you can bind a `javascript` function with a jqplot event `jqplotDataHighlight` to show a custom value on mouse hover.

See this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10415281/841632)